# Remotely Access Apache NiFi (v1.11.4)

Tags: apache-nifi

I am running Apache NiFi (version1.11.4) on my local machine say on port (8090).
It runs & is working good on my machine.
This is normal setup without registry/certificate/LDAPS/security.

I want to access this NiFi on other machine running with in the private Network.
For this i enabled this 8090 port on my machine's firewall (as inbound rule with TCP)

But not able to access NiFi remotely

I tested both the cases (with default port and custom post):

**Case 1**: on my local machine NiFi is running on port 8080, i setup firewall inbound rule also on port 8080 Other member should be able to access my NiFi instance remotely on port 8080.

```
nifi.web.http.host=MY_HOST_NAME 
nifi.web.http.port=8080
```

**Case 2**: On server machine NiFI is running on port 8090, i setup firewall inbound rule also on port 8090 Other member should be able to access this NiFi instance remotely on port 8090.

```
nifi.web.http.host=MY_HOST_NAME 
nifi.web.http.port=8090
```

**nifi.properties file:**

```
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=MY_HOST_NAME
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
```

Comment: this question to your firewall and network config. nifi is a usual server that listens tcp.

Comment: @daggett I tried firewall side also.. we are able to access other servers like PostgreSQL and able to connect remotely but not NiFi................ Can any one suggest what special setting is required with this NiFi so that same NiFi become accessible on another machine.

Comment: by default nifi listens http port 8080 on all network interfaces. just after nifi has started you should see in the logs lines like: `JettyServer http://192.168.99.1:8080/nifi` - what do you have?. if you have port 8090 - then it means you have changed the default nifi parameters - what do you have in `nifi.properties` file for `nifi.web.*` properties?

Comment: please put it into the question - impossible to read in comments.

Comment: look into a log file for lines like this just after nifi has started: `JettyServer http://HHHHHH:PPP/nifi` - show please what do you have there

Comment: are you able to access nifi locally by using `http://MY_HOST_NAME:8080/nifi` ?

Comment: Yes I am able to access in NiFi in local (host) machine (but not in remote machine)
NiFi hosted on my local machine shows this in log file: org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://MY_HOST_NAME:8080/nifi

Comment: NiFi hosted on my local machine shows this in log file: "org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http: //MY_HOST_NAME:8080/nifi"

Comment: on remote machine could you do `ping MY_HOST_NAME` ?

Comment: Yes already tried & was able to ping host on remote machine, this is something else seems NiFi is by default binding to private IP address & so not accessible from outside. If some one try it practically will see the same issue.

Comment: it binds to `nifi.web.http.host`. and if it's empty it binds to all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use machine IP instead of hostname.
After setting machine IP in appropriate file `nifi-1.22.0/conf/nifi.properties`

Something like this

```
nifi.web.https.host=192.168.5.141
nifi.web.https.port=8443
```

Start **nifi** with this command `./nifi.sh start`
You can see is nifi running properly with monitor open ports.

```
$ ss -tupeln

tcp    LISTEN     0      50                 192.168.5.141:8443                                       *:*                   users:(("java",pid=9705,fd=3221)) uid:1001 ino:66401 sk:ffff9e1c734f9740 <->
```

Running phase of nifi may take long time be patient.
After see ip:port in output of `ss` command access nifi web console with below address.

```
https://192.168.5.141:8443/nifi/login
```